# SPen convert image to text

Tags: android, sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am trying to get started with the SPen SDK. Does the SDK provide any method to convert user's image into a text from SCanvasView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S Pen SDK (v2.2.5) does not provide any API for text/handwriting recognition.

Comment: we do have the sdk v3 , could you please assist how to convert handwriting to text using it ?